# Isekai manga where the protagonist transports some jewels/diamonds from a safe that can't be opened by carrying it

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Many years ago I read a manga I found quite good and I am trying to find it again.

It takes place in an isekai/overwordly world where people see the protagonist as a bit weak. But there was a mission he got where he should transport some diamonds/jewels but the problem was that the items were stuck in a big heavy safe that could not be opened, and he just lifts it up with zero problems.

Comment: Do you remember any other details? You say isekai, but was the main character transported from another world into where the story takes place? Was he on Earth before or another fantasy world? Was he just naturally strong or did he become enhanced via some unexpected method?